# Is having a return type of Task enough to make a method run asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a simple method that does a complicated string operation and returns the result. As you can see, the return type of this method is `Task<string>`. Therefore, I can use `Task.FromResult(result)` to return the value of my string.

```cs
public Task<string> ComplexOperation()
{
    string result = // Do something complex
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Then, I can use the `await` keyword to call this method.

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var myResult = await ComplexOperation();
}
```

Because I am awaiting `CompelxOperation()`, (waiting for the Task to return on completion) will this method run asynchronously?

Comment: ..have you tried it? ;)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes, it works. Just not sure if it is actually running asynchronously.

Comment: @MatthewTrip no it will not) Cause `Task.FromResult` is not asynchronous operation)

Comment: Returning a `Task` does not make it asynchronous, but `await`ing it does... if the `Task` has not already completed, such as when using `Task.FromResult` as Guru says

Comment: So do I need to use TaskCompletionSource to make it run asynchronously?  @GuruStron

Comment: It actually depends on what you are tying to achieve.

Comment: @GuruStron I don't have a specific goal I just want to make a method that returns a string run asynchronously. All the info online seems to be stupidly confusing.

Comment: Can you provide more practical example. Also please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth).

Comment: @GuruStron my example is this https://paste.mod.gg/taserowera.cs According to you this won't run asynchronously but if not then how would I make it run asynchronously

Comment: @MatthewTrip `await Task.Delay(..)` to the rescue =) Usually you will need tho run something asynchronously if you have IO-bound (or CPU-bound operation which you want to offload to other thread for some reason)

Comment: @MatthewTrip yes it will not. Compiler is smart enough to generate code which will not introduce unnecessary context switching if operation is already completed when you hit the `await` instruction.

Comment: @GuruStron so is the simple logic I have in that method not a cause of concern for IO issues? And what is the point of Task.Delay? It will make it async sure, but it just delays the Task without doing anything.

Comment: @MatthewTrip missed the `// Do something complex` comment. Yes, you will need `TaskCompletionSource` and offload you work to another thread, so it will not block the calling one.

Comment: @MatthewTrip or just `Task.Run(..)` will do the job.

Comment: Returning `Task` just means that it's awaitable.  Being asynchronous depends on the actual implementation.  The code in your link has no reason to be async.  You'd want to use async mostly for I/O (DB call, webservice call, reading from a file) or if you have something that is CPU intensive then you'd use `Task.Run` to offload it to another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments you need to do something like this:

```
public Task<string> ComplexOperation()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>  /* Do something complex */);
}
```

You can play with it like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before" );
    var myResultTask = ComplexOperation();
    Console.WriteLine("After task creation");
    var result = await myResultTask;
    Console.WriteLine("After async await");
}

public Task<string> ComplexOperation()
{    
    Console.WriteLine("Creation");
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In before work");
        Thread.Sleep(500); //simulate work;
        Console.WriteLine("In after work");
        return "Done";
    });
}
```

And compare the behavior with switching to your implementation when you just return `Task.FromResult`. Also it does not makes much sense in such test example, TBH.

Comment: @Servy In my view, using `Task.Run` implies unnecessary overhead of creating state machine that could be avoided by using `Task.FromResult(result)`. And if we use combination of `async`, `await` and `Task.FromResult(result);` , then code would be *asynchronous*.

Comment: @StepUp `Task.Run` doesn't create a state machine.  `async` creates a state machine.  You're literally talking about turning a non-state machine solution into one that *is* one, the opposite of what you've said.  Additionally, `async`, `await` are tools for manipulating async operations, `Task.Run` is a tool for *creating* an asynchronous operation (by running a synchronous method asynchronously in a thread pool thread).  Your answer provides something that's *not even asynchronous*.  It's just a synchronous method with some added state machine overhead providing no value.

Comment: @Servy Ok, I see! However, why does [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)  say that method is asynchronous?

Comment: @StepUp It doesn't.  It says it's a method that uses the `async` keyword.  Not that the method is actually asynchronous.  That can indeed be confusing, that a method with the `async` keyword is no necessarily asynchronous, but it is still true (as that example demonstrates).

Comment: @Servy ok, in my view this phrase **A call to method GetLeisureHours that isn't immediately awaited returns a Task<int>,** says that method is not *immediately* awaited, so is it not correct conclusion that method is asyncronous?

Comment: @StepUp No.  It's saying that the method returns a `Task<int>`.  It's literally just a fact about the return type of the method, and nothing more.  It does not say that the method is asynchronous.  Also note that the comment specifically states that `FromResult` is used as a placeholder for a method that's *actually* asynchronous, and it's discussion of the method is based on that, rather than the placeholder (not that it actually says the existing method is actually asynchronous either).

Comment: @Servy I really appreciate your answer and it has value for me, however, the sentence `that isn't immediately awaited returns a` could not be evaluated to be synchronous. Please, be very kind and please, explain me why I should think that code is synchronous if `method GetLeisureHours that **isn't immediately awaited** returns a Task<int>`

Comment: @StepUp You should think that `GetLeisureHourse` returns a `Task<int>` because *that's the return type of the method*.  It can't be any other type, because that's the type that the definition of the method says it returns, and that's what the quote says.  Of course, if you `await` that, the type of that expression is `int`, because when you await a `Task<T>` it resolves to an expression of type `T`, that's just how `await` works, and the quote is indicating that the type is only a `Task` before the caller `await`s.  None of that has anything to do with whether or not the method is synchronous.

Comment: @Servy ok, thank you! I will upvote your answers from your profile! However, this phrase says `that isn't immediately awaited returns a Task<int>`. So is it would be a correct assumption that current thread while awaiting Task<int>, could be free for other works and execute some commands for some milliseconds and receive info from state machine whether `Task<T>` resolved to `T`?

Comment: @StepUp The code generated by `await` will first check whether the awaitable object is completed, and if it is, it will get the result (if applicable) and continue synchronously.  It will not release control to the caller unless the awaited object has not completed.

Comment: @Servy ok, but what happen if it is not completed? Docs says **isn't immediately awaited** , *It will not release control to the caller unless the awaited object has not completed*, however, thread in this time will not be suspended and will do other work?

Comment: @StepUp This method *is* returning a completed task though.  A method that returns a task that *isn't* complete is one that is not synchronous.  That's true whether or not the caller awaits it immediately.

Answer (score -2):

Just as you flagged as async the Main method to get an asynchronous method you need to flag the method as asynchronous with the async keyword, and make the result a Task.

But in the framework Tasks are used for 2 related but different concepts, parallelization and asynchronous programming.

What you are doing is use parallelization.

So you are just running some synchronous code on  a different thread.

Based on your example i think what you need is to use parallelization, which can speed up some complex calculation or work by use many threads to work in parallel.

The concept behind asynchronous code is to free the thread while you are waiting for external resources (like some data from a web service), to allow other work to be done in the meantime.

So, if you need to do complex work with local resources it's better use tasks without async logic, instead when working with remote resources you can go for asynchronous operations.

Answer (score -2):

Semantically the method `ComplexOperation` is asynchronous because it returns an awaitable type, and in order to follow [the guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) it should be named `ComplexOperationAsync`.

> Asynchronous methods in TAP include the `Async` suffix after the operation name for methods that return awaitable types, such as `Task`, `Task<TResult>`, `ValueTask`, and `ValueTask<TResult>`.

But it is not a well behaved asynchronous method. An asynchronous method is expected to return an incomplete `Task` immediately, allowing the caller to `await` the task asynchronously without been blocked. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#initiating-an-asynchronous-operation):

> An asynchronous method that is based on TAP can do a small amount of work synchronously, such as validating arguments and initiating the asynchronous operation, before it returns the resulting task. Synchronous work should be kept to the minimum so the asynchronous method can return quickly.

The `ComplexOperation` method does exactly the opposite: it forces the calling thread to perform the complex operation, and finally it hands back a completed task. For all intents and purposes this operation is not asynchronous at all. It is 100% synchronous and 0% asynchronous, plus some overhead (to add insult to injury). So don't do this, and if there is some library that does it, don't use the library. It is simply bad practice.

---

**Clarification:** Since the term *asynchronous method* can mean different things in different contexts, I should clarify that the context of this answer is the perspective of the consumer, who sees the signature of the method as a contract, and builds expectations based on the visible contract and not on the invisible implementation. In this context the method `ComplexOperation` is asynchronous. If we switch perspective and focus on the implementation, the method `ComplexOperation` is not asynchronous. My statement *«it is simply bad practice»* refers to the practice of breaking the contract, and providing a synchronous implementation to a method with asynchronous contract. I am not criticizing the use of `Task.FromResult` method per se. I am criticizing it only when it follows a complex/lengthy/latent operation, that according to the method's contract should be made asynchronous.

P.S. I am thankful to @DmytroMukalov for providing (in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214037/discussion-on-answer-by-theodor-zoulias-is-returning-a-task-enough-to-make-the-m)) the helpful distinction between asynchrony by contract and by implementation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214037/discussion-on-answer-by-theodor-zoulias-is-returning-a-task-enough-to-make-the-m).