# _ = Task.Run vs async void | Task.Run vs Async Sub

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

*In a console application. I need to load some long running code (network-stuff, REST calls) off my main thread. I want to pass it to a background thread and don't block the calling thread. I will invoke events in that method to handle it's result.*

Is there any difference beetween doing this,

```cs
public async Task MainThreadAsync() {
    _ = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingAsync());
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomethingAsync()
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
```

or doing this?

```cs
public async Task MainThreadAsync() {
    DoSomethingAsync();
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomethingAsync()
}

private async void DoSomethingAsync() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
```

---

VB.Net:

```vb
Public Async Function MainThreadAsync() As Task 
    Task.Run(Async Function() As Task
                 Await DoSomethingAsync()
             End Function)
    ' Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomethingAsync()
End Function

Private Async Function DoSomethingAsync() As Task
    ' Doing long running stuff
End Function
```

vs

```vb
Public Async Function MainThreadAsync() As Task 
    DoSomethingAsync()
    ' Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomethingAsync()
End Function

Private Async Sub DoSomethingAsync()
    ' Doing long running stuff
End Sub
```

Or is there even a better way?
Also, is there a difference beetween c# and vb.net in this regard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly: *do not use* `async void`. I realize that it expresses the *semantics* of what you want, but there are some framework internals that *actively explode* if they encounter it (it is a long, uninteresting story), so: don't get into that practice.

Let's pretend that we have:

```cs
private async Task DoSomething() {...}
```

in both cases, for that reason.

---

The main *difference* here is that *from the caller's perspective* there is no *guarantee* that `DoSomething` won't run synchronously. So in the case:

```cs
public async task MainThread() {
    _ = DoSomething(); // note use of discard here, because we're not awaiting it
}
```

`DoSomething` will run on the main thread *at least* as far as the first `await` - specifically, the first **incomplete** `await`. The good news is: you can just add:

```cs
await Task.Yield();
```

as the first line in `DoSomething()` and it is *guaranteed* to return immediately to the caller (because `Task.Yield` is always incomplete, essentially), avoiding having to go via `Task.Run`. Internally, `Task.Yield()` does something *very similar* to `Task.Run()`, but it can skip a few unnecessary pieces.

Putting that all together - if it was me, I would have:

```cs
public async Task MainThread() {
    _ = DoSomething();

    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomething()
}
private async Task DoSomething() {
    await Task.Yield();

    // Doing long running stuff
}
```

Comment: I never saw that use of Task.Yield. So basically you are saying that this would be even better than using Task.Run? What's the difference exactly? Also, asking because of vb, can't you then just Await the DoSomething()?

Comment: @Fox if you *await* the `DoSomething`, then you're going to be stuck waiting (asynchronously) for `DoSomething` to get to the end of whatever it is doing - probably not what you want. As for `Task.Yield()` vs `Task.Run` - perhaps a matter of choice, and it *really won't matter* unless you're doing it *a hell of a lot*. If this was IO library internals: I'd use `Task.Yield()` simply to shave a few allocations, but: *you will never notice the difference in your scenario*. So: use whichever you find clearer.

Comment: But wouldn't `Task.Yield()` instantly return a finished task and therefore resolve the await? Or how does it work?

Comment: @Fox `Task.Yield()` represents an incomplete async state; it doesn't mean "the end of DoSomething" - it just prevents the *current thread* from doing the work. `Task.Yield` essentially means "there's more to do, but I don't want to tie up the current thread; hand control back to the caller, and do the next bit of this work on the thread-pool". The key bit here is surrendering the synchronous call path. We then want to *discard* the result of that (because we don't care about it), not await it. If we await it: we're waiting for it to *finish everything it has to do*

Comment: @Fox in other news: async is complex :)

Comment: @MarcGravell - sorry to hop on someone else's question but as you aren't awaiting DoSomething, could you have used public void MainThread() instead of making it an async task?  What's would be the difference?

Comment: @JonRoberts read the first line :) as for the details: some sync-context implementations actively hate it; as one example, `AspNetSynchronizationContext` - see the `OperationStarted` method in the ref source; if it encounters `async void`, it deliberately throws. So: *generalizing* that: a sync-context - something that is **outside of your control** (usually) - can cause your program to fault if you use `async void`. That's a pretty good reason to not use `async void` :) link: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs,108

Comment: @JonRoberts it is *possible* that I'm biased in this, but a lot of my work is developing libraries that are used by developers on systems and frameworks that *they* choose, not me. If you're a library developer, you *really, really* want to avoid these kinds of environment-specific problems. If you're an application developer and you know that your code will never ever have a sync-context: use it, I guess? but it feels like knowingly burying a landmine in the code for someone else to find in a few months/years (when they port the code to some other environment).

Comment: I think he means to remove the async attribute from the mainthread entirely.

Comment: @JonRoberts if you just mean not making `MainThread` async *at all*; that really depends on whether `MainThread` has other things it needs to `await` in the "other stuff". If it doesn't: sure, make if non-async - that's fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes I meant removing the async attribute completely in the above example where there were no other await calls.  It was just for my own understanding.  That's for the explanation, it been really helpful.

Comment: @JonRoberts mostly, I left them because there was no await on the *original* code, so it isn't like I was removing it - and because there is a commented out "other stuff" bit; my assumption is that the "other stuff" does some awaiting

Comment: *`Task.Yield` essentially means "there's more to do, but I don't want to tie up the current thread; hand control back to the caller, and do the next bit of this work on the thread-pool".* - Isn't this only true when there is no synchronization context? When there is a synchronization context (ASP.NET or UI app), wouldn't you have to use `await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(false)` for that to be true?

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes, you're right; but there *is no*  `ConfigureAwait` for `YieldAwaitable`, so... :shrug:

Comment: Huh... look at that.... I guess you could substitute that with something like `await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false)` if you really wanted.

Comment: @GabrielLuci or even better use `Task.Run`. Which enforces cleanly that whatever code it contains will run in a `ThreadPool` thread. Unlike the `Task.Yield`, which is at a best a hack in this case IMHO.

Comment: @Fox it is a good hack if it works, and this one doesn't work in applications with `SynchronizationContext`, like WinForms and WPF. The continuation of `Task.Yield` will not run in a `ThreadPool` thread in this case. If this is what you want, just use `Task.Run` which works everywhere. As for the performance, I haven't measured it but I don't expect the difference to be impressive, if there is any difference at all.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's a console application. But I'll keep it in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding c#, this case:

```
private async void DoSomething() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
public async task MainThread() {
    DoSomething();
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomething()
}
```

will run `synchronously`, because what can be awaited is Task and there isn't any Task created.
However this code:

```
private async task DoSomething() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
public async task MainThread() {
    _ = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething());
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomething()
}
```

will run asynchronously (fire-firget) as you are explicitly creating and starting the new Task

Comment: But when I test the first case, the code below DoSomething() just continues without waiting like the second version. Why is that?

Comment: whether DoSomething runs synchronously really depends on the internal of DoSomething - it will run synchronously *as far as the first incomplete await* (/cc @Fox)

Comment: As @MarcGravell mentioned, if code hidden behind `// Doing long running stuff` is synchronous (no Tasks started) then it is running synchronously

Comment: "no Tasks started" is not the same thing as synchronous; asynchronous can mean a *lot* of things, and in **almost all cases** it doesn't mean "starting a task"; the task API was retrofitted as one way of *expressing* asynchronous state, but the two are not synonymous. Even most `async` methods that return `Task[<T>]`: never "start" a task

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference. But first lets follow the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) and append the `Async` suffix to the asynchronous methods `DoSomething` and `MainThread`:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
public async Task MainThreadAsync() {
    _ = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingAsync());
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomethingAsync()
}
```

This one ensures that the `DoSomethingAsync` will run on a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread from start to finish. The main thread will not run even a single line of the `DoSomethingAsync` method. It will just schedule a `Task` to run on the `ThreadPool`, which is a minuscule job measured in nanoseconds, and then continue executing the other stuff. A possible exception in the `DoSomethingAsync` method will never be observed. Unless you handle the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event (to get a non-deterministically delayed notification), or change a specific setting in App.config, or you are running on .NET Framework 4.0.

```
private async void DoSomething() {
    // Doing long running stuff
}
public async Task MainThreadAsync() {
    DoSomething();
    // Continue with other stuff and don't care about DoSomething()
}
```

This one will start running the `DoSomething` on the main thread, and will return when it encounters an `await` for a non-completed awaitable. Conceptually you could say that the `DoSomething` is composed by two parts, the synchronous part and the asynchronous part. The first part will run on the main thread, and the second part will run on a `ThreadPool` thread (because your app is a Console app and has no [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) unless you [install one manually](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext)).

The `DoSomething` is [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), so a possible exception in the `DoSomething` method will be thrown on the current `SynchronizationContext`, or on the `ThreadPool` if there is none installed. Which means that your Console app will crash uncontrollably, after raising the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event. Which in some cases may be exactly what you want. For example if you are 100% sure that the `DoSomething` should never throw in normal conditions, then crashing immediately may be preferable to letting the app continue running with a potentially corrupted internal state. In general though you should try to minimize the usage of both fire-and-forget tasks and `async void` methods, because they make your program more confusing and unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you, I always forgot the convention. Added the Async to the methods.

Comment: @Fox AFAIK the async void methods are not considered asynchronous methods (because they don't have an asynchronous contract), so they should not have the `Async` suffix. But I am not sure that there is a consensus [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837259/is-returning-a-task-enough-to-make-the-method-async/61837980#61837980).