# Using TaskCompletionSource to transform library into an awaitable one?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm using a non-async USB library from a USB chip manufacturer but I want it to be async so that using USB doesn't lock up the UI. I'm trying to learn to code the "right" way and according to my research, for IO bound tasks such as this we want to use `TaskCompletionSource` instead of `Task.Run =>` (which is more appropriate for CPU bound tasks). The tutorials on TaskCompletionSource are pretty sparse and the ones that do exist are not explained well for the noob.

After creating wrappers for the library methods using TaskCompletionSource I'm finding that the UI still blocks sometimes (although it behaves much better than without). Here's an example of my wrapper method:

```
public static Task<bool> SendMessageAsync(byte[] msg, int sizeOfMsg)
{
    uint bytesWritten = 0;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Use of library "Write" method
    usbStatus = connectedUSBDevice.Write(msg, sizeOfMsg, ref bytesWritten); 

    if(usbStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
    {
       tcs.SetResult(false);
    }
    else
    {
       tcs.SetResult(true);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then to use I simply await this:

```
 isOK = await USBLibrary.SendMessageAsync(data, size);
```

Is this implementation incomplete? What do I need to do to ensure this does not block the UI?

Comment: First of all sendmessageasync is not at all async, it is running synchronously. In case usb driver has a way to notify that write operation is complete I mean events then u can subscribe and modify the code which would be truly async. Check this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/) for more insight on taskcompletionsource.

Comment: Does device accept multiple commands without waiting for a command to complete?Making an application work Async where the device will not accept multiple commands will never work.A robust multiple command system will only work under two conditions 1)There is a one-to-one mapping.So for every command you get only one response and the response come in same order that commands were sent 2)If the mapping is not one-to-one then you need an id for each command so you can match the responses with the command that got sent.Otherwise, When an error how would you know which command caused the error.

Comment: Ya, the intention of the code is to have the IO bound functions run synchronously, but then asynchronously relative to the UI. Because in most cases we'll need writes and reads to complete before doing anything else with the USB chip. But a long running write (say sending a firmware update packet or something) doesn't mean we need to stop any CPU or UI elements from say displaying a progress bar/ status updates and preparing the next packet. I just want any of these library functions to be non-blocking. How do we do that?

Comment: A common misconception is that if you tack on the keyword `async` on your method, it will run on a separate thread. It will not, it will instead tell the compiler to rewrite your method to a state machine, based on your usage of the keyword `await` inside the method. If you do not add this `await` keyword, your entire method will still be synchronous, as before, and you will get a warning about the `async` keyword not being needed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I did understand that part, at least I had a primitive understanding that the cpu is essentially dividing up clock cycles for both tasks. A simple example might be in the case of a USB write, the UI is setup and rendered, then UI thread sends the data to the USB chip's buffers and maybe checks back with the UI in between every byte or so written. I did however think that using async *might* move the task to a new thread if it appeared to require too many resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) class is a useful mechanism when you have some event or other source of asynchronous notification, and want to consume it as a `Task`. Apparently this is not the case in your example. Your `SendMessageAsync` method is practically equivalent to this:

```
public static Task<bool> SendMessageAsync(byte[] msg, int sizeOfMsg)
{
    uint bytesWritten = 0;
    var usbStatus = connectedUSBDevice.Write(msg, sizeOfMsg, ref bytesWritten);
    return Task.FromResult(usbStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK);
}
```

So it's a method with an *asynchronous contract* and a [*synchronous implementation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837259/is-returning-a-task-enough-to-make-the-method-async/61837980#61837980). Which is not good. It is [much better](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) to expose a synchronous API, and let the callers do the wrapping themselves (with `Task.Run`).

```
public static bool SendMessage(byte[] msg, int sizeOfMsg)
{
    uint bytesWritten = 0;
    var usbStatus = connectedUSBDevice.Write(msg, sizeOfMsg, ref bytesWritten);
    return usbStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;
}
```

Caller:

```
bool result = await Task.Run(() => SendMessage(msg, sizeOfMsg));
```

Comment: The only place you would implement a method as stating it is asynchronous, but actually being synchronous, is if you have to implement an interface or contract that is using asynchrony, but your *thing* that you implement it over isn't actually asynchronous at all.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias: So in other words, the way I was doing it originally was the right way, haha!? Thank you, I can follow your code and explanation very well, plus it shows some ways to refactor my code.

Comment: @Theordor Zoulias: At times I use the USB library methods in series, say SendCmd() then DeviceHandshake() then SetOutPin(). Those all need to complete synchronously before moving to the next one, but again we want this whole sequence to not interfere with the UI. Is it best to use `await Task.Run(() =>` around each method or is it better to wrap the entire sequence in `await Task.Run(() =>`?

Comment: @liquidair it is practically the same. There is not much of a difference. I should note that the recommendation about not exposing asynchronous wrappers applies mainly to library code. If you are an application developer and you find yourself wrapping with `Task.Run` the same synchronous methods over and over again, then by all means go on and write some helper async wrapper methods to make your life easier. Just make sure that these methods will stay local to your project, and won't become libraries some day in the future!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Ok, that's sort of what I was getting at. If I find myself using groups of the library methods over and over like that I do just create a method, but I keep it private for the page it's relevant to. Prolly easiest just to keep those helper methods synchronous and call the helper like ; `await Task.Run(() => HelperMethod(params));` vs putting the `Task.Run()` inside.

Comment: @liquidair yeap, use your judgement. These are just recommendations, not strict rules. :-)