# How do I run a method both parallel and sequentially in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a C# console app. In this app, I have a method that I will call `DoWorkAsync`. For the context of this question, this method looks like this:

```
private async Task<string> DoWorkAsync()
{
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

  var random = new Random();

  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  var length = random.Next(10, 101);

  await Task.CompletedTask;
  return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

I call `DoWorkAsync` from another method that determines a) how many times this will get ran and b) if each call will be ran in parallel or sequentially. That method looks like this:

```
private async Task<Task<string>[]> DoWork(int iterations, bool runInParallel)
{
  var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
  for (var i=0; i<iterations; i++)
  {
    if (runInParallel)
    {
      var task = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync());
      tasks.Add(task);
    }
    else
    {
      await DoWorkAsync();
    }
  }

  return tasks.ToArray();
}
```

After all of the tasks are completed, I want to display the results. To do this, I have code that looks like this:

```
var random = new Random();
var tasks = await DoWork(random.Next(10, 101);
Task.WaitAll(tasks);

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
  Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```

This code works as expected if the code runs in parallel (i.e. `runInParallel` is `true`). However, when `runInParallel` is false (i.e. I want to run the Tasks sequentially) the `Task` array doesn't get populated. So, the caller doesn't have any results to work with. I don't know how to fix it though. I'm not sure how to add the method call as a `Task` that will run sequentially. I understand that the idea behind Tasks is to run in parallel. However, I have this need to toggle between parallel and sequential.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not following the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) correctly. Both `DoWorkAsync` and `DoWork` [are asynchronous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837259/is-having-a-return-type-of-task-enough-to-make-a-method-run-asynchronously/61837980#61837980), so both should have the `Async` suffix in their names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the `Task` array doesn't get populated.

So populate it:

```
else
{
  var task = DoWorkAsync();
  tasks.Add(task);
  await task;
}
```

P.S.

Also your `DoWorkAsync` looks kinda wrong to me, why `Thread.Sleep` and not `await Task.Delay` (it is more correct way to simulate asynchronous execution, also you won't need `await Task.CompletedTask` this way). And if you expect  `DoWorkAsync` to be CPU bound just make it like:

```
private Task<string> DoWorkAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // your cpu bound work
        return "string";
    });
}
```

After that you can do something like this (for both async/cpu bound work):

```
private async Task<string[]> DoWork(int iterations, bool runInParallel)
{
    if(runInParallel)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, iterations)
            .Select(i => DoWorkAsync());
        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = new string[iterations];
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            result[i] = await DoWorkAsync();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay in case of sequential execution - yes. My wording is not fully correct, the `DoWork(int iterations, bool runInParallel)` is "generalized" for both cases, since I don't know which one OP is actually using.

Comment: Yes you're right. Might be better to make `DoWork` sync though, then `Select(i => Task.Run(DoWork))` to parallelise. That way, the overhead introduced by `Task.Run` wouldn't be present for the sequential processing i.e. `result[i] = DoWork();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off doing the following:

1. Create a function that creates a (cold) list of tasks (or an array `Task<string>[]` for instance). No need to run them. Let's call this `GetTasks()`

`var jobs = GetTasks();`

2. Then, if you want to run them "sequentially", just do

```
var results = new List<string>();
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    var result = await job;
    results.Add(result);
}
return results;
```

If you want to run them in parallel :

```
foreach (var job in jobs) 
{
    job.Start();
}
await results = Task.WhenAll(jobs);
```

Another note,

All this in itself should be a `Task<string[]>`, the `Task<Task<...` smells like a problem.

Comment: What is reason for `Parallel.ForEach` in second case?

Comment: @GuruStron that's actually not fitting well the context of OP, I'll change to `Task.WhenAll`

Answer (score 1):

Why is `DoWorkAsync` an `async` method?

It isn't currently doing anything asynchronous.

It seems that you are trying to utilise multiple threads to improve the performance of expensive CPU-bound work, so you would be better to make use of `Parallel.For`, which is designed for this purpose:

```
private string DoWork()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    var random = new Random();

    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var length = random.Next(10, 101);
    
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}

private string[] DoWork(int iterations, bool runInParallel)
{
    var results = new string[iterations];

    if (runInParallel)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, iterations - 1, i => results[i] = DoWork());
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) results[i] = DoWork();
    }
    
    return results;
}
```

Then:

```
var random = new Random();
var serial = DoWork(random.Next(10, 101));
var parallel = DoWork(random.Next(10, 101), true);
```